# 1D data classification

Tags: r, vectorization

This R code separates the values in `rData`. They are classified according to the class in `rClass`.

To do that, `ClassifiedrData` is a named list, where each element in the list (a class), should be a vector with all the elements in that class.

It is slow, and I had read that I should not use `for` in R, but I have no clue on how to vectorize it.

(I do not necessarily need a dictionary, so I welcome another data structure to store the classified numbers if it is more practical.)

I made random data (`rData` and `rClass`) as an example, but my real data is not random (so I simply creating the data classified is not a solution)

```
CreateEmptyDictionary <- function(names) {
    mylist.names <- names
    mylist <- vector("list", length(mylist.names))
    names(mylist) <- mylist.names
    return(mylist)
}


#Random integers
rData <- sample(x = as.integer(c(1:100)), size = 100)

#Random class  
rClass <- sample(x = c(1:10), size = 100, replace = TRUE)

#Separate rData according to his class in rClass
i <- 0
ClassifiedrData <- CreateEmptyDictionary(names <- sort(unique(rClass)))

for (a in rData) {
    i <- i + 1
    #ClassifiedrData[[rClass[i]]] <-  append(ClassifiedrData[[rClass[i]]], a)
    ClassifiedrData[[rClass[i]]][length(ClassifiedrData[[rClass[i]]])+1] <- a
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a 1-liner with the built-in `split` function:

```
ClassifiedrDataSplit <- split(rData, rClass)
```

You can confirm this returns the same result as your original code:

```
identical(ClassifiedrData, ClassifiedrDataSplit)
# [1] TRUE
```

In addition to being a lot less code, this will result in sensible speedups for larger datasets. For instance, consider the performance with 10 million elements and 10 classes:

```
rData <- sample(x = as.integer(c(1:1e7)), size = 1e7)
rClass <- sample(x = c(1:10), size = 1e7, replace = TRUE)
system.time({i <- 0
ClassifiedrData <- CreateEmptyDictionary(names <- sort(unique(rClass)))

for (a in rData) {
    i <- i + 1
    #ClassifiedrData[[rClass[i]]] <-  append(ClassifiedrData[[rClass[i]]], a)
    ClassifiedrData[[rClass[i]]][length(ClassifiedrData[[rClass[i]]])+1] <- a
}})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   5.248   0.435   5.749 
system.time(split(rData, rClass))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.258   0.083   0.357
```

The solution with `split` is about 10x faster.

Comment: Wow! How do you find the right function. Do you have the entire libraries in your head?

Comment: Thank you. Have a prize https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fD7ji3YOwcM

Comment: @zexot Unfortunately R has a huge number of these special-purpose functions that you just need to know or you spend a lot of time reinventing the wheel. I guess through time you pick up the ones that have come in handy a few times.